# How to enable or disable the checkbox based on property value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my DataGrid I've a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` implementation:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Selected}"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCheckBoxColumnStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCheckBoxColumnEditingStyle}">
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
             <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                 <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="Match_Unchecked"/>
                  <Style.Triggers>

                                        <!-- Enabling -->
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsAdding, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                        </DataTrigger>

                                        <!-- Disabling -->
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsAdding, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>

        </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

as you can see I've inserted a `DataTrigger` on the `Style` of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, so essentially when the property `IsAdding` is false, the `Cell` with the content inside should be enabled, otherwise, disabled.

This doesn't seems to working, the `Cell` is even enabled, why?

Comment: Have you tried setting the style target to `CheckBox` rather than `DatGridCell`? Does your event setter even works?

Comment: @XAMlMAX the `CheckBox` is inside the `DataGridCell` and I can't have two style in one

Comment: I understand that but I am not asking you to set another style in there, I am asking to change the target type. And does your event setter works?

Comment: @XAMlMAX if I change the `TargetType` I get this error: `TargetType 'CheckBox' does not match the type of item 'DataGridCell`

Comment: FYI, I've just used your code (slight modification for MVVM, replaced with your `EventSetter` with a `Button` toggle), but it seems to be working.

Comment: Well what you need in there is a style for a `ComboBox` but to get that you would need to define the template for the column and then use the style that you defined using a `x:Key`. That is because the Templates are not part of the visual tree so the styles will NOT be applied unless defined explicitly. I hope this makes sense. And you still haven't answered if your event setter works!

Comment: @XAMlMAX That's right, I've created a separated style and now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the [LogicalTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/trees-in-wpf) of your application. The code you have there should actually work just fine, but it appears that you may be testing this [inside of the demo application](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Grids.xaml#L23-L35). Normally this would be fine, however there was an addition of a control to display XAML that is breaking the logical tree ([I have a fix](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/smtx) in progress but it is not complete yet).

You can work around this by making two changes to the demo application:

1. In the [MainWindow.xaml](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/MainWindow.xaml#L88) replace the `XamlDisplayerHost` with a regular `ContentControl`
2. In [Grids.xaml](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Grids.xaml#L18) replace the `XamlDisplayerPanel` with a regular `StackPanel`

After that your style should work as you expect.